# How to center an image overlaid on a div *but* have the image centered by its bottom rather than its center?

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and a bit stuck on how to modify my CSS to fix this issue.

So I have some code that is working for the most part. I have a div containing (simplified):

```
        <div id="map">
            <div id="mapContainer"/>
            <img id="iconOnMap" src="pinSource"/>
        </div>
```

And basic CSS placing the image in the center of the mapContainer div:

```
    #iconOnMap {
        width: 2em;
        height: 2em;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    #map {
        width: 95vw;
        height: 55vw;
        position: relative;
    }

    #mapContainer {
        position: absolute;
        width: inherit;
        height: inherit;
    }
```

However, the image is centered in the div at its *center*, whereas, I want the *bottom* of the image to be at the center, not the *center* of the image to be at the center.

An illustration of the issue:

[image]

In the image above, the blue marker is pointing to the correct location and the red pin indicates the incorrect behavior. Whereas the pin's middle is where the center currently is, the pin's bottom / pinpoint should be at the center instead. Any tips on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the middle because you're telling it to be in the middle. Instead of:

```
#iconOnMap {
        ...
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        ...
    }
```

Try:

```
#iconOnMap {
        ...
        transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
        ...
    }
```

That should translate it in the Y direction by the icon's full height instead of half its height.